# C# LinqToExcel, Distinct showing all results - tried online solutions, couldn't solve

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-excel

```
  var ItemMaster = new ExcelQueryFactory("E:\\Group Item Master.xlsx");

        var ItemList = (from x in ItemMaster.Worksheet()
                        select new
                        {
                            CategoryName = x["CategoryName"],
                            GroupName = x["GroupName"],
                            ModelNo = x["ModelNo"],
                            Description = x["Description"],
                            Code = x["Code"]
                        }).ToList();


        var DistinctCategory = ItemList.Select(x => x.CategoryName).ToArray().Distinct();
        //shows categoryname repeated


        var iteml = ItemList.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryName);
        var DistinctCategoryTwo = iteml.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
        //shows categoryname repeated
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's really repeated and not in different case or with extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was linqToExcel specific issue

```
 var CategoryList = ItemList.Select(x => x.CategoryName.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

value column was needed to fix it

Comment: You don't need that `ToList` before the `Distinct`